# How to make ToC ignore a chapter?

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, chapters, abstract

I am writing a report. There is a page with my abstract, which I don't want to appear in the ToC.

I start the **abstract.tex** file with the following command:

```
\chapter{Abstract}
```

In my **main.tex** file, I input it using the following command:

```
\begin{document}
...
\input{abstract}
\tableofcontents
\input{Chapter1}
...
\end{document}
```

All of my other chapters are added using the `\input{}` command.

The problem is that the abstract chapter is presented in my ToC, which I do not want it to. Any suggestions on how to fix this?

p.s. I am not that experienced with latex. I just gave the code that I think is relevant. If more pieces of code are needed, let me know.

Comment: `\chapter*{Abstract}`

Comment: I also suppose the abstract doesn't have to be numbered. If this is inded the case, using `\chapter*` should solve the problem.

Comment: It is IMHO not correct to start an abstract with a `\chapter` command. Most document classes have means to typeset an abstract, e.g. `\begin{abstract}...\end{abstract}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer @PhelypeOleinik gave worked.

Just use:

```
\chapter*{Abstract}
```